# setInterval overriding others setIntervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create multiples setIntervals and store them (and clear later), but when I do this, the last setInterval override the previous, executing one time for each previous setInterval , but with the same content.

Code snippet with the weird behaviour :

```js
var timeoutFunctions= {};

function log_on_console(text){
  console.log(' > > > inside function : '+text)
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      console.log(' > > > before function : '+i)
      timeoutFunctions[i] = setInterval(function(){log_on_console(i)}, 2000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the output on console is :

```
" > > > before function : 0" js:21:6
" > > > before function : 1" js:21:6
" > > > before function : 2" js:21:6
" > > > before function : 3" js:21:6
" > > > before function : 4" js:21:6

" > > > inside function : 5" (5) js:16:2 //(this one is the "problem")
```

I was expexcting something like this instead :

```
" > > > before function : 0" js:21:6
" > > > before function : 1" js:21:6
" > > > before function : 2" js:21:6
" > > > before function : 3" js:21:6
" > > > before function : 4" js:21:6

" > > > inside function : 0" js:16:2 
" > > > inside function : 1" js:16:2 
" > > > inside function : 2" js:16:2 
" > > > inside function : 3" js:16:2 
" > > > inside function : 4" js:16:2
```

so, why is the last `setInterval(function(){log_on_console(i)}, 2000)` overriding the previous four?

Comment: Hint : search about closures :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function here:

```
timeoutFunctions[i] = setInterval(function(){log_on_console(i)}, 2000);
```

...has an *enduring reference* to the `i` variable, not a copy of its value as of when the function was created. So it uses the value `i` has as of when it's *called*.

If you wanted to burn the *value* of `i` into the function as of when you create the function, you could use `Function#bind`:

```
timeoutFunctions[i] = setInterval(function(val){log_on_console(val)}.bind(null, i), 2000);
```

or more directly as your anonymous function there is just calling `log_on_console`:

```
timeoutFunctions[i] = setInterval(log_on_console.bind(null, i), 2000);
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, will call the original function with `this` set to the first argument you give `bind`, and passing along any additional arguments. Since your function isn't using `this`, I just used `null` for that arg. E.g.:

```
function foo(a) {
    console.log("a = " + a);
}
var f = foo.bind(null, 1);
f();
```

shows us:

```
a = 1
```

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you don't declare `i` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

use closure()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(' > > > before function : ' + i)
        (function (curent) {
            timeoutFunctions[curent] = setInterval(function () {
                log_on_console(curent)
            }, 2000);

        })(i)
    }
});
```

Comment: I can think of two reasons: 1. They were confused, as many will be, by the various different meanings of `i`, which is why I always use a different name for the arg. 2. Code dumps without explanation are less than useful. *Edit* Appears they've retracted the downvote, though. Also, creating extra throw-away functions in a loop isn't a great idea, either.

Comment: @mplungjan yes ..you are correct

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I must admit I finally grok this closure better than your bind

Comment: @mplungjan: I should add a sentence of explanation about that. *Edit* Done